# Blank page or flash before transition when write android app with jquerymobile

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I use jQueryMobile and PhoneGap to make my android app, everything goes well but the transition, it always shows after a blank page or flash.

The simple transitions code like below:

```
<a href="#product_list"  data-transition="slide">Go to Product list </a>
```

Any one can help? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with the phonegap. But I had worked with the html and j query for developing a complete web application.I was also having the same problem when I was working with the j query. When ever you are developing an app with html and scripts it should be so lite then oly we can implement the transitions.Actually I dint get rid of this problem completely but still i was able to remove the blank page to about 95% when I used JQMOBI instead of j query. J query is bit heavy i predict.That must be the reason for the blank page.So u can refer [JQMOBI](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/index.php) Which i hope will solve your problem.Its so lite and you can use the default transitions of this app framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if it works for you):

```
<a href="#product_list"  data-transition="none">Go to Product list </a>
```